# Georeferncing issue QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm trying to georeference a GE satellite image and I've got the below problem. What I am doing wrong?

I want it as same as a square polygon to start mapping.

[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry, I neither get your question, nor see any problem. Could you expand?

Comment: This looks like a screenshot of part of a QGIS Georeferencer dialog. Where have the red lines come from?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are doing anything wrong - you just haven't run the geo-referencer yet. Those red lines are your tie-points. What are you trying to achieve?